# Coding dichotomous variable based on changes in the relative highest score between a set of variables

Tags: r

I want to code a new variable in a dataframe based on a set of rules. I have a dataframe df1 with a subject variable, a time variable, and variables A, B and C, like this:

```
subject <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
A <- c(1,7,7,6,6,5,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA)
B <- c(2,1,1,1,1,1,6,5,4,NA,NA,NA)
C <-c(7,1,6,1,6,1,6,2,4,NA,NA,NA)

df1 <- data.frame(subject,time,A,B,C)
```

Values in A, B, and C range from 1 (lowest) to 7 (highest), there are also some NA. Now I want to code a new dichotomous variable, newvar. The first row for every subject should always be coded 0. 1 should be coded whenever the variable/s with the highest score (A,B or C) within one row change/s to one or more different variable/s in the next row. It doesn't matter if the value changes from one row to the next within one variable, only if there is a change in which of the three variables has the highest score within one row compared to the previous row.

The examples from df1 should make this clearer:

- Row 1 is coded 0 because it is the first row for subject 1. C has the
  highest score among the three variables A, B, and C.
- In row 2, A has the highest score. Therefore, newvar = 1.
- In row 3, A still has the highest score, therefore, newvar = 0.
- In row 4, A still has the highest score --> newvar = 0.
- In row 5, now A and C both have the highest score, therefore,
  newvar = 1.
- In row 6, only A has the highest score again, therefore, newvar = 1.
- Row 7 is the first row for subject 2, therefore newvar is coded 0.
- In row 8, newvar should be coded 1, because in the previous row, B
  and C equally had the highest score, now it is only B.
- In row 9, newvar should again be coded 1, because now B and C have
  the highest score again within the row.
- Rows 10 to 12 should be coded NA.

This is what it should look like:

```
newvar <-c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,NA,NA,NA)
df2 <- data.frame(subject,time,A,B,C,newvar)
```

I would greatly appreciate any input in how to go about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. First, pivot your data into long form. Then, for each `subject` `time` combination, collect the column names that are equal to the highest value for that combination. This is stored as `highest_values`.

Then, change the group to `subject`. For each `subject` check if the `time` is the lowest value of `time` - if it is, code as 0 (there are alternative options if you just want to code 0 for the first row independent of time value). If the `highest_values` does not have any column names, code as `NA`. If there is a difference between `highest_values` and the previous row (a change), code as 1. Otherwise, it assumes `highest_values` has not changed, and code as 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(subject, time)) %>%
  group_by(subject, time) %>%
  summarise(highest_values = toString(name[which(value == max(value))])) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(newvar = case_when(
    time == min(time) ~ 0,
    highest_values == "" ~ NA_real_,
    highest_values != lag(highest_values) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>%
  right_join(df1)
```

**Output**

```
   subject  time highest_values newvar     A     B     C
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1     1 "C"                 0     1     2     7
 2       1     2 "A"                 1     7     1     1
 3       1     3 "A"                 0     7     1     6
 4       1     4 "A"                 0     6     1     1
 5       1     5 "A, C"              1     6     1     6
 6       1     6 "A"                 1     5     1     1
 7       2     1 "B, C"              0     1     6     6
 8       2     2 "B"                 1     2     5     2
 9       2     3 "B, C"              1     3     4     4
10       2     4 ""                 NA    NA    NA    NA
11       2     5 ""                 NA    NA    NA    NA
12       2     6 ""                 NA    NA    NA    NA
```

**Edit (2/11/21)**: Based on the comment below, sometimes there are rows with missing data. In these cases, `newvar` should reflect the last or most recent "highest_values" excluding those rows.

To do this, would `filter` out those rows without a "highest_values" value before the `group_by`. Then, the most recent "highest_values" will be the value that is not missing. Also, you won't need to set `newvar` as `NA` - this will happen automatically with the `right_join`.

Here is the revised code:

```
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(subject, time)) %>%
  group_by(subject, time) %>%
  summarise(highest_values = toString(name[which(value == max(value))])) %>%
  filter(highest_values != "") %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(newvar = case_when(
    time == min(time) ~ 0,
    highest_values != lag(highest_values) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>%
  right_join(df1) %>%
  arrange(subject, time)
```

I added a row of data to demonstrate with an example.

**Output**

```
   subject  time highest_values newvar     A     B     C
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1     1 C                   0     1     2     7
 2       1     2 A                   1     7     1     1
 3       1     3 A                   0     7     1     6
 4       1     4 A                   0     6     1     1
 5       1     5 A, C                1     6     1     6
 6       1     6 A                   1     5     1     1
 7       2     1 B, C                0     1     6     6
 8       2     2 B                   1     2     5     2
 9       2     3 B, C                1     3     4     4
10       2     4 NA                 NA    NA    NA    NA
11       2     5 NA                 NA    NA    NA    NA
12       2     6 B, C                0     2     3     3
```

Comment: This worked really nicely, thank you! However, adapting this to my real data I encountered one more coding issue that's complicating things a bit further: For some subjects there are rows with missing values in the middle of the time series, not just at the end of it. In those cases, it would be better to compare the value in "highes_values" not with the value in the previous row, but with the value in the previous row that contains values. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: @jwin See edited answer - does this work for what you described?